# fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install cocoapi but I do not have Python.h. I read that I need to install python-dev but I do not have sudo. Are there any other **easy** ways to get Python.h? Will I get Python.h if i install anaconda?

```
(env_pytorch) haziq@vita-workstation2:~/cocoapi/PythonAPI$ python3 setup.py install --user
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing pycocotools.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pycocotools.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to pycocotools.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to pycocotools.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'pycocotools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'pycocotools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
skipping 'pycocotools/_mask.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/haziq/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I../common -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c ../common/maskApi.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/../common/maskApi.o -Wno-cpp -Wno-unused-function -std=c99
../common/maskApi.c: In function ‘rleDecode’:
../common/maskApi.c:46:7: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
       for( k=0; k<R[i].cnts[j]; k++ ) *(M++)=v; v=!v; }}
       ^~~
../common/maskApi.c:46:49: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
       for( k=0; k<R[i].cnts[j]; k++ ) *(M++)=v; v=!v; }}
                                                 ^
../common/maskApi.c: In function ‘rleFrPoly’:
../common/maskApi.c:166:3: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
   for(j=0; j<k; j++) x[j]=(int)(scale*xy[j*2+0]+.5); x[k]=x[0];
   ^~~
../common/maskApi.c:166:54: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
   for(j=0; j<k; j++) x[j]=(int)(scale*xy[j*2+0]+.5); x[k]=x[0];
                                                      ^
../common/maskApi.c:167:3: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
   for(j=0; j<k; j++) y[j]=(int)(scale*xy[j*2+1]+.5); y[k]=y[0];
   ^~~
../common/maskApi.c:167:54: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
   for(j=0; j<k; j++) y[j]=(int)(scale*xy[j*2+1]+.5); y[k]=y[0];
                                                      ^
../common/maskApi.c: In function ‘rleToString’:
../common/maskApi.c:212:7: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
       if(more) c |= 0x20; c+=48; s[p++]=c;
       ^~
../common/maskApi.c:212:27: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
       if(more) c |= 0x20; c+=48; s[p++]=c;
                           ^
../common/maskApi.c: In function ‘rleFrString’:
../common/maskApi.c:220:3: warning: this ‘while’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
   while( s[m] ) m++; cnts=malloc(sizeof(uint)*m); m=0;
   ^~~~~
../common/maskApi.c:220:22: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘while’
   while( s[m] ) m++; cnts=malloc(sizeof(uint)*m); m=0;
                      ^~~~
../common/maskApi.c:228:5: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     if(m>2) x+=(long) cnts[m-2]; cnts[m++]=(uint) x;
     ^~
../common/maskApi.c:228:34: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
     if(m>2) x+=(long) cnts[m-2]; cnts[m++]=(uint) x;
                                  ^~~~
../common/maskApi.c: In function ‘rleToBbox’:
../common/maskApi.c:141:31: warning: ‘xp’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
       if(j%2==0) xp=x; else if(xp<x) { ys=0; ye=h-1; }
                               ^
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/haziq/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I../common -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c pycocotools/_mask.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/pycocotools/_mask.o -Wno-cpp -Wno-unused-function -std=c99
pycocotools/_mask.c:4:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means python-dev is not installed. Can you try running
 `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: Hello and thanks for the suggestion. But I already mentioned that I do not have sudo.

Comment: you are welcome i can suggest you to see the following article : Install python packages for local user without sudo 
  http://ernie55ernie.github.io/python/2016/11/11/install-python-packages-for-local-user-without-sudo.html